# SQL Server Group By and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a count of invoices by country within region. Below is a view of my table structure and required output. I have tried to do a basic view (not looking at CustomerArea yet as I want to get the basics right first) of this but cannot get into a nested mode.

[image]

```
SELECT Customerregion, COUNT(InvoiceNo ) AS CountCol1
FROM [Data-Warehouse].[dbo].[Master]
WHERE Customerregion='Europe'
GROUP BY Customerregion, InvoiceNo
```

Below is a view of the output for Europe only based on the above?

**I am sorry to ask a simple question here.**

CustomerArea    CustomerRegion  InvoiceNo
Romania Europe  INV001
Romania Europe  INV002
Netherlands Europe  INV003
Netherlands Europe  INV003
Netherlands Europe  INV003
Netherlands Europe  INV004
Italy   Europe  INV005
Italy   Europe  INV005

[image]

Comment: Why are you grouping by the `InvoiceNo` as well?

Comment: And why are you grouping by `customerregion` if you restrict you result to one single `customerregion`

Comment: Just `GROUP BY Customerregion` should do it.

Comment: Thank you derpirscher, you are right - that can be removed. There will be multiples area and I added the clause to try and get to a result.

Comment: Yes, Group By Customerregion gives me a full count, but want to try and break it down by unqieue invoiceno. I wias thinking to group by the unique invno

Comment: If you want it by `InvoiceNo` why are you not returning `InvoiceNo` in the `SELECT`?

Comment: Please don't show your sample data as image, but as text. If it was text then we could copy/paste it to create a temporary table and try out your query, correct it and then provide you with an answer. But since it is in an image, we would have to type over all your sample data, that is not our job but yours. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @GuidoG - I wasn't expecting you to create a temp table - will do in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine all you need is this, Once you have this data you can count the totals for a region and also do a grand total in the calling code.

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataTable;

CREATE TABLE #DataTable (
    CustomerArea VARCHAR(20),
    CustomerRegion VARCHAR(20),
    InvoiceNo VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO #DataTable (CustomerArea, CustomerRegion, InvoiceNo)
VALUES
('Romania', 'Europe', 'INV001'),
('Romania', 'Europe', 'INV002'),
('Netherlands', 'Europe', 'INV003'),
('Netherlands', 'Europe', 'INV003'),
('Netherlands', 'Europe', 'INV003'),
('Netherlands', 'Europe', 'INV004'),
('Italy', 'Europe', 'INV005'),
('Italy', 'Europe', 'INV005');

SELECT CustomerRegion, CustomerArea, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfInvoices
FROM #DataTable
GROUP BY CustomerArea, CustomerRegion
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew - I get totally where it is going wrong now - thank you again. So, what I was trying to get to ultimately is what you produced, but clearly I got myself confused very quickly earlier in the play. Overthinking it probably, I don't know. Cheers