Add a default value to a field when using INSERT and NOT EXISTS
I hope you can offer some guidance or some additional reading reference.
I am using a query to insert new PO's from Table2 into Table1 using WHERE NOT EXISTS. Table1 has a comments field. Am I am able to set the field = 'TBC' at the point of doing the new record insert?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Table1



PONumber
PODate
POComments




PO-123456
11/05/2024
TBC



Table2



PurchOrder
PODate




PO-123456
11/05/2024



INSERT INTO Table1
(
    PONumber,
    PODate
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    PurchOrder,
    PODate
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    Select PONumber
    From Table1
    WHERE Table1.PONumber = Table2.PurchOrder
);


Specify Default Values for Columns

Please do not use images, use formatted text

Of course you can just insert the literal 'TBC' as part of your existing insert

Please re-read what you typed earlier (Jul 26, 2022 at 9:25) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120484/sql-server-group-by-and-count#comment129142640_73120484    You type "will do in the future!", in respond to "Please don't show your sample data as image"

@MrJackson no, problem I did use [edit] to do the change for you  (this time... )

You can add a literal while inserting, as all rows are new rows and need the same tag.
Your insert command will be:
INSERT INTO Table1
(
    PONumber,
    PODate,
    POComments
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    PurchOrder,
    PODate,
    'TBC' as POComments
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    Select PONumber
    From Table1
    WHERE Table1.PONumber = Table2.PurchOrder
);


No reason to alias the column I'm the select though

@DaleK - It makes it more self documenting without having to count the columns

@MartinSmith if one had a few more than 3 maybe :)

@Pradeep Pai Kateel What do you mean by "tag"?

@JonasMetzler I believe the meant value. "[...] all new rows need the same value", hence the literal string

Thank you all for your comments - I have learnt something new. Marked as accepted

@DaleK - what is the minimum number of columns in play for you to consider labeling them? Because you clearly have an opinion.
